# What is the time complexity for this function for detecting cyclic linked lists?

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

I just tried using unordered_map to detect a cyclic linked list (i know this a bad idea).

The code snippet for my isCyclic() function in my class named linked_list is this:

```
    bool linked_list::isCyclic(Node * head)
{
  Node * trav = head;
  unordered_map<Node *, int > visited;

  while(trav != NULL)
  {
    if(visited[trav->next_ptr] == 3)
        return true;
    visited[trav] = 3;
    trav = trav->next_ptr;
  }
  return false;
}
```

For each new node i check if the next_ptr points to a node which is already visited and if yes then i return true else i just set that node as visited and update trav to the next node to visit till there is a cyclic situation or till all nodes are traversed.

I would wan't to know what is the Big O Notation for this algorithm because according to my calculation its O(n*n) which is i guess wrong as i am not that accurate always.

Comment: By what means did you arrive at O(n^2) ? Or was that a guess, similar to your conclusion it is wrong?

Comment: Because the while loops for all the nodes and the time complexity of unordered_map as i read on some forums is O(n) . That is the reason why i thought it to be O(n^2) but as i mentioned before i am an absolute beginner in this topic so there's a 99% chance that i am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complexity of the provided algorithm is `O(n)`. The reason is simply because unordered_map and unordered_set both provide constant insertion, search, and removal time per the requirements of the standard library. Therefore, given an average constant-time `k`, the complexity becomes `O(k*n)`, which is equivalent to `k*O(n)`, and ultimately has a fundamental complexity of `O(n)` as the constant `k` becomes irrelevant.

To demonstrate this, the following example reduces your cycle search to a most-basic case of using a `std::unordered_set`, which is little more than a `std::unordered_map`, where the key maps to self.

```
bool check_for_cycle_short(const Node *p)
{
    std::unordered_set<const Node*> mm;
    for (; p && mm.insert(p).second; p = p->next);
    return p != nullptr;
}
```

Note that `std::unordered_set<T>::insert` returns a `std::pair` of `iterator,bool`, where the latter indicates whether an insertion actually took place because the key wasn't found before insertion.

Now consider this example, which is `O(n^2)`:

```
bool check_for_cycle_long(const Node *p)
{
    for (; p; p = p->next)
    {
        for (const Node *q = p->next; q; q = q->next)
        {
            if (q == p)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This exhaustively searching the remainder of the list with each node, thereby performing `(n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3).... + (n-(n-1))` comparisons.

**Example**

To see these in action, consider the following short program, which loads a linked list with 100000 nodes, then checks both for cycles in worst-case (there are none):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <chrono>
#include <unordered_set>

struct Node
{
    Node *next;
};

bool check_for_cycle_short(const Node *p)
{
    std::unordered_set<const Node*> mm;
    for (; p && mm.insert(p).second; p = p->next);
    return p != nullptr;
}

bool check_for_cycle_long(const Node *p)
{
    for (; p; p = p->next)
    {
        for (const Node *q = p->next; q; q = q->next)
        {
            if (q == p)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;

    Node *p = nullptr, **pp = &p;
    for (int i=0; i<100000; ++i)
    {
        *pp = new Node();
        pp = &(*pp)->next;
    }
    *pp = nullptr;

    auto tp0 = steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << check_for_cycle_short(p) << '\n';
    auto tp1 = steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << check_for_cycle_long(p) << '\n';
    auto tp2 = steady_clock::now();

    std::cout << "check_for_cycle_short : " <<
        duration_cast<milliseconds>(tp1-tp0).count() << "ms\n";
    std::cout << "check_for_cycle_long  : " <<
        duration_cast<milliseconds>(tp2-tp1).count() << "ms\n";
}
```

**Output** (MacBook Air duo-core i7 @ 2.2gHz)

```
false
false
check_for_cycle_short : 36ms
check_for_cycle_long  : 7239ms
```

As expected, the results reflect what we suspected.

Comment: Thanks for that excellent explanation. Is the code which i provided not correct? I mean is it not giving the correct output for different test cases?